# Dividing two matrix row 1 to row 1 ... row n to rown n

Tags: matlab, matrix, division

how can I divide matrix if I want to divide it by row one to row 1 of another matrix. for example:
i have a matrix of a complex no.

```
Z = [(3+4i) ; (4+5i)]
```

and another mtrix of

```
V= [0 1 -3 -2 -7 -4; 0 -4 1 -3 -4 -5]
```

i want to divide row 1 of V to row 1 of Z so that the answer would be this

```
I = [0 (0.12-0,16i) (-0.36+0.48i) (-0.24+0.32i) (-0.84+1,12i) (-0.48+0.64i); 0 (-0.3902+0.4878i) (0.0975-0.1216i)....]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [bsxfun](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html)

```
I = bsxfun(@rdivide,V,Z);
```